# How to view the realtime volume output?

Tags: audio

Is it possible to view the realtime volume output (e.g in terminal)? By this I don't mean the volume which will be a static value between 0 and 100, but rather the variation in output volume as something such as an mp3 file is playing. The aim is to use this to make LED's pulse with music, rather than having to use a seperate microphone.

Comment: Do you mean the real values sent to the DAC's ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- C.A.V.A. - Console-based Audio Visualizer for ALSA https://github.com/karlstav/cava

Noteable mentions:

- SoundMeter - https://pypi.org/project/soundmeter/
- PavuMeter (GUI) - https://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/pavumeter/
- jkmeter (GUI) - https://kokkinizita.linuxaudio.org/linuxaudio/downloads/

Comment: About SoundMeter (a nice tool indeed to be listed) AFAIR it outputs the RMS of fragments. That is somehow different from the real values sent to the DAC. (even if, I do acknowledge that RMS is actually more meaningful to me)

Comment: the first two seem to capture audio using a microphone, and the second two are GUI so i havent looked at them. Rather than capturing the audio strength using a microphone I want to accurately obtain the audio strength using the values sent to the speaker. Is this possible?

Comment: Nevermind, cava seems to work as desired, thanks!